# Display inline images into td

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, html-table

I just want to display inline 3 icons that I have into a td from the table, and I can't find the way to do it.

I got this code:

```
<table id="tableResults" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
      <thead style="border-bottom:1px solid #EEEEEE; line-height: 2em;">
         <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadas</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadsa</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadsa</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadsa</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">ABBVIE</td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></td>
            <td><i class="icon icon-view_list"></i><i class="icon icon-view_list"></i><i class="icon icon-view_list"></i></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

and I always got the result displayed in block. I tried out from td with img and ul li and it worked with display: inline, but not here into the td with i tag.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Are you currently using bootstrap with this project?

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap css yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked fine:

```
<table id="tableResults" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
      <thead style="border-bottom:1px solid #EEEEEE; line-height: 2em;">
         <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadas</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadsa</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadsa</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">dsadsa</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">ABBVIE</td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></td>
            <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Which means there's probably something wrong with your styles on icon. I'd try and match them with the styles on glyphicon.

```
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I'd particularly look and see if the base class of icon has a display of inline-block.